# Lifting platforms is not working as it should

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to make some lifting platforms in my game, so if the platform went down, the characters can't go over it. I have written a script for it, but for some reason the "lifting up" is not working as intended. It won't go back to its starting place, but it will go a bit below. And for some reason it won't go smoothly to the place where it should, just "teleport" there and done. I thougt multiplying Time.deltaTime with a const will help, but it is the same.

Here is my code, any help would be appreciated:

```
public class LiftingPlatform : MonoBehaviour {
private Transform lift;

private bool isCanBeLifted;
private float timeToLift;
public float timeNeededToLift = 5f;

private Vector3 startPos;
private Vector3 downPos;
private Vector3 shouldPos;

private bool isDown;

public GameObject[] collidingWalls;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    lift = transform;

    isCanBeLifted = true;
    timeToLift = 0f;

    isDown = false;

    startPos = transform.position;

    downPos = new Vector3(startPos.x, startPos.y - 5f, startPos.z);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    timeToLift += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timeToLift >= timeNeededToLift) {
        if (isCanBeLifted) {
            if (isDown) {
                shouldPos = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, downPos, Time.deltaTime * 10);
                lift.position = new Vector3(shouldPos.x, shouldPos.y, shouldPos.z);
                isDown = true;
            }
            else if (!isDown) {
                shouldPos = Vector3.Lerp(downPos, new Vector3(startPos.x, startPos.y, startPos.z), Time.deltaTime * 10);
                lift.position = new Vector3(shouldPos.x, shouldPos.y, shouldPos.z);
                isDown = false;

            }
        }
        timeToLift = 0;

    }


    if (!isDown) {
        for (int i = 0; i < collidingWalls.Length; i++) {
            collidingWalls[i].SetActive(true);
        }

    }

    else if (isDown) {
        for (int i = 0; i < collidingWalls.Length; i++) {
            collidingWalls[i].SetActive(false);
        }
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) {
    if (collider.tag == "Player" || collider.tag == "Enemy") {
        isCanBeLifted = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider) {
    if (collider.tag == "Player" || collider.tag == "Enemy") {
        isCanBeLifted = true;
    }
    }
}
```

These lifting platforms are a child of another Platforms object.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are updating the object's position every frame. You are only checking if the total time passed is greater than the time needed to lift, and then updating the position to a value that is dependent on the delta time (using the `Vector3.Lerp` function).

What I would do is in the update step, if `timeToLift` is greater then `timeNeededToLift`, subtract the latter from the former and invert the value of `isDown`. Then, in your `Vector3.Lerp`, make the third argument `(timeToLift / timeNeededToLift)` instead of `(Time.deltaTime * 10)`. Can you try that and see if it works?

The third argument for `Vector3.Lerp` is the "blending factor" between the two vectors, 0 is the first vector, 1 is the second, and 0.5 is in between. If the total time is greater than the time needed to lift, but the delta time is not greater than 1, it will get the position of the platform using a blending factor of less than 1, resulting in a platform that didn't move fully.

Comment: Thx the answer, but I would like to only move my platform when 5 timeToLift is bigger than timeNeededToLift, so for example is timeNeededToLift is 3, I would only like to move down it after 3 secs, and after it I would like to wait 3 secs and then move it up.

Comment: In that case, you may want to use a numerical value for the state of your platform instead of a boolean.

Basically, in my answer, your platform has two states, moving up and moving down. Whenever `timeToLift` exceeds `timeNeededToLift`, the state is moved forward by inverting the value of `isDown`.

What you want to do is have four states, moving up, stopped at the top, moving down, stopped at the bottom. You can use an integer to hold this. To increment the state, add 1 and modulo by 4. For states 0 and 3, use the current behavior, and for states 1 and 4, don't update the position.